# Rasberry pi 4 channel relay switch off after 10 seconds

Tags: python, relay

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
def mist():
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

        # setup and switing on relay
        GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.LOW)
        # sleep for 30 second
        time.sleep(30)
        # off relay
        GPIO.output(4,  GPIO.HIGH)

        # clean up all
        GPIO.cleanup()

if __name__ == "__main__":
        mist()
```

what I am trying to do that to on 4 channel relay module for 30 seconds.

Problems that I am facing

1. Even if I set out put pin to `GPIO.HIGH`it won't switch on. (I think my relay is ACTIVE LOW, so I set initial=GPIO.LOW for switching on)
2. I set time.sleep for 30 seconds but relay switch off after 2 or 10 seconds

Why this happening, I am new to python and Rasberry pi

**EDIT**

The problem was 1-Wire Interface option was switched on.
GPIO4 is the default for 1-wire. If that is activated in /boot/config.txt it may interfere with other hardware connected to that pin

[dirk](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/42636/dirk) pointed out the issue.

Comment: @Hi Ebin Manuval, have you tried testing your code with an LED instead of a relay?

Comment: @David No i hav't tried it

Comment: I suggest you try that first, and see if you observe the same odd timing behavior. If you don't, and your LED switches state after 30 seconds, then I'd suspect it's a matter of how your relay is connected to the RPi.

Comment: I tried it with the LED but same result

Comment: how many seconds pass before the LED goes from low to high? I just tried the same code and I'm having no problem.

Comment: It worked when I changed gpio pin to 18. I don’t know why it is not working with gpio 4

Comment: since you are Broadcom Mode, can you confirm by looking at this [diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaU6t.png) that you were using GPIO pin 4, which is numbered as pin 7 (the number is inside the circle)?

Comment: GPIO4 is the default for 1-wire. If that is activated in /boot/config.txt it may interfere with other hardware connected to that pin

Comment: @Dirk Thanks for the info, I think that was the issue.

Comment: @Dirk Why not make that an answer?  It would help close off the question and we could reward you with an up vote.

Comment: @joan Done. It took me a while. Had to lock a few car parks first 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GPIO4 is the default for the 1-wire interface. If that is activated in /boot/config.txt it may interfere with other hardware connected to that pin.

Check config.txt for a line like this:

```
dtoverlay=w1-gpio
```

To deactivate it you can remove this line manually or use one of the Pi configuration utilities (`raspi-config` or the one in the GUI under 'Preferences').
You will need to reboot after changing the configuration.